# Validate visual flow screen fields using 3rd part javascript library

Tags: salesforce, lightning

I am creating a Visual Flow and I have few address fields which needs to be verified via 3rd part Address Verification javascript library(Smarty Street API). I am not able to find how to invoke this javascript inside my visual flow screen.
However the same address verification API is integrated with one of my VF page but I want to implement the same inside Visual Flow.

Can someone please guide on this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no ability to call JavaScript functions placed on your Visualforce pages from Visual Flow.